# ModuleNotFound quanto tento importar uma biblioteca externa

Tags: python, importação

```
pip install pillow
```

```
>>> Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\miguel\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (8.3.1)
```

```
import pillow
```

```
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miguel\PycharmProjects\Testing\main\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pillow
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'
```

por algum motivo eu sempre consigo esse erro quando tento importar uma biblioteca externa, mesmo depois de baixa-la. tentei pesquisar mas sem resultados. alguém sabe o motivo desse erro?

Answer (score 0):

Se a biblioteca for para manipulação de imagens o correto é:

### Instalação

```
pip install Pillow
```

**Nota** `Pillow` com a letra `P` em maiúsculo.

### Carregando

```
import PIL
```

ou

```
from PIL import Image
```